# Dynamic redirecting the request from Apache Web server

Tags: apache, redirect, web, weblogic, http-status-code-404

We  have an apache web server through which we redirect requests to Weblogic App server.
Now in case the application on the weblogic server is down, the Apache Web server should detect it and redirect to a static html page(something like saying - application is unavailable currently, instead of showing 404 error).

Can someone please help how this can be implemented ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `ErrorPage` directive within the plugin configuration. When apache is unable to connect to Weblogic, you can redirct to a customer error page located somewhere on apache itself.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e14395/plugin_params.htm) is here

Comment: THanks. just wanted to know whether I can add a local url. I checked on the internet, everywhere in example they have given proper url . I just to show a static page which I can store on the same web server.